# Android paste text from clipboard after restarting the phone

Tags: android, restart, clipboardmanager

I am using android clipboard manager and trying to paste a string to my android app as mentioned in [developer.android.com tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html).
I can paste string in normal circumstances but there is a problem in following scenario.

Scenario:

I copy a string from text file. Then restart the phone/android device. Then I run my app. 
Now in my appliciation clipBoard.hasPrimaryClip() function returns false.
So there should be no data copied in clipboard.
But if I open a text file or open Skype i can paste the string which was copied before restarting the phone/android device.

So how can I get the string that was copied to clipboard before restart.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine they are using some other persistent storage for clip data. Maybe try to write the clip data to a database or something that doesnt get wiped on reboot.